# count based on a specific field in SOLR

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

How to return the count of a field with each object in Solr

When I do `fq=verify_ix:1` I have a response below, I want to get count where  verify_ix = 1 in the response too. How can I do that?

```
"response": {
    "numFound": 9484,
    "start": 0,
    "maxScore": 1,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "10000000000965509",
        "description_s": "No Description",
        "recommendation_ix": 0,
        "sId_lx": 30005938,
        "sType_sx": "P",
        "condition_ix": 1000,
        "verify_ix": 1
      },
      .
      .
      .
      {
        "id": "10000000000965734",
        "description_s": "No Description",
        "recommendation_ix": 1,
        "sId_lx": 30005947,
        "sType_sx": "P",
        "condition_ix": 2000,
        "verify_ix": 1
      }
]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want counts of the different values for a given field, you can send a request to Solr with `facet=true` and `facet.field=verify_ix`.  For counts over all records, set `q=*:*`. If you don't want to see any rows returned, you can set `rows=0`.

See here for more details on faceting:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting

(I tested this with Solr 5, but faceting should work with Solr 4 as well.)

Comment: Thankyou, `verify_ix ` can only be `1 or 0` I observed that I get the same results for `{!tag=0}verify_ix` or {!tag=1}verify_ix. Why would that be? in what situation `tag` should be used?